# Why are my Login Items cleared upon restart?

Tags: macos, restart, login-items

Since I have been using OS X El Capitan 10.11.3 (Beta 15D13b), most of my login items are not remembered. With the exception of Dropbox and WD Quick, all other applications I put into Login Items (e.g. Chrome, Mail) are removed from the list again after a reboot.

This is quite annoying; none of my apps launch (regardless of whether I've set them to hide at default) and the list is apparently cleared upon launch.
What is the cause for this, and how can this be solved?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a beta and I would report this bug to Apple

Comment: @Mark are you sure? I would say it is not necessarily/proven exclusive to the beta version. I think the issue (login items not remembered) and the solution (re-create the .plist file) could be of use to any users with problems regarding the login items.

Comment: We don't close beta questions as off topic. See [meta] for the discussion as well as [help] for the latest of what's off topic.

Comment: [This still happens in 11.3.1.](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/305731/4395)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't comprehend the behavior of LoginItems in El Capitan 10.11.3.

But one measure is to delete *com.apple.loginitems.plist* and then re-populate it from scratch.

Another workaround is to simply lock the file after adding all items which should be started after logging in.

Comment: I have deleted the file, logged in and out and from that point onwards, the edits to my login items were actually saved to the .plist file. Thanks!