# Why does High Sierra remove my Login Items?

Tags: high-sierra, login-items

After updating to macOS 10.13.1, my Login Items have vanished. Some [users have reported this behavior in earlier betas](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/224894/4395), but this is the first time I've experienced it in a release.

Is there a reason for this behavior. Is there a way to identify what items I had configured  so I can restore them?

Answer (score 1):

I have lost all my login items too after upgrade to macOS 10.13.1.

You could [take a look the plist file](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/5278/how-do-i-open-a-plist-file) at `~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.loginitems.plist`, it may still contain names of login items, then add them back manually. I recovered mine in this way.

I guess 10.13 has moved login items config to [somewhere else](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/8086931?start=0&tstart=0) but failed to migrate old ones.